# Keep multiple Slick slider sycronzed

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

I have three slick sliders and I slide the three of them with the same arrows.

One slider with images, another slider with dates and another slider with text content.
And it is partially working.
The problem I have is that after a few clicks, there seems to be some kind of desynchronization between the sliders and I end up with the image in the wrong date and/or the wrong content.
Maybe I need to find a way to make sure that one animation or slide is finished sliding to go to the next one?
How can I make sure that a slide has been slided for keep sliding the next one? Or how can I make sure to slide the rest if one has been slide?
It seems that sometimes the last click on one of the arrow with the next and prev functions slides the .slider-for but it doesn not slide the other two.

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
    $('.slider-for').slick({
        centerMode: true,
        centerPadding: '10.5em',
        slidesToShow: 1,
        arrows : false,
        swipe: false,
        draggable: false,
        touchMove: false,
        responsive: [
            {
              breakpoint: 768,
              settings: {
                centerMode: true,
                centerPadding: '2em'
              }
            },
            {
              breakpoint: 576,
              settings: {
                centerMode: true,
                centerPadding: '2em'
              }
            },
            {
                breakpoint: 1200,
                settings: {
                    centerMode: true,
                    centerPadding: '3em'
                }
            }
        ]
    });
    $(".slider-nav").slick({
        slidesToShow: 7,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        dots: true,
        swipe: false,
        
        draggable: false,
        touchMove: false,
        centerMode: true,
        arrows : false,
        focusOnSelect: true,
        responsive: [
            {
              breakpoint: 768,
              settings: {
                centerMode: false,
                slidesToShow: 3,
              }
            },
            {
              breakpoint: 576,
              settings: {
                centerMode: false,
                slidesToShow: 3
              }
            },
            {
              breakpoint: 1200,
              settings: {
                centerMode: false,
                slidesToShow: 5
              }
            },
            {
                breakpoint: 1500,
                settings: {
                  centerMode: false,
                  slidesToShow: 5
                }
            }
        ]
    });
    $(".slider-content").slick({
        slidesToShow: 1,
        swipe: false,
        draggable: false,
        
        touchMove: false,
        slidesToScroll: 1,
        dots: false,
        arrows : false,
        fade: true
    });
    const buttonPrev = $('<button>', {
        class: 'slick-prev slick-arrow',
        'aria-label': 'Previous',
        id: 'prevSlide',
        type: 'button',
        text: 'Previous'
    });
    const buttonNext = $('<button>', {
        class: 'slick-next slick-arrow',
        'aria-label': 'Next',
        id: 'nextSlide',
        type: 'button',
        text: 'Next'
    });
    $('.slider-nav').append(buttonPrev);
    $('#prevSlide').click(function(){
        slidePrev();
    });
    $('.slider-nav').append(buttonNext);
    $('#nextSlide').click(function(){
        slideNext();
    });
});
function slideNext() {
    const sliderNav = $('.slider-nav');
    const sliderContent = $('.slider-content');
    const sliderFor = $('.slider-for');
    let selector = '.slick-current > img, .slick-current > #video-slide > iframe';
    let total = $(selector).attr('total');
    let index = $(selector).attr('index');
    if ((index == total - 1) || (total == 1)) {
        const sliderForPromise = new Promise((resolve) => {
            sliderFor.slick('slickNext');
            sliderFor.on('afterChange', function () {
                resolve();
            });
        });
    
        sliderForPromise.then(() => {
            sliderContent.slick('slickNext');
        }).then(() => {
            sliderNav.slick('slickNext');
        });
    } else {
        sliderFor.slick('slickNext');
    }
    
}
  
function slidePrev() {
    const sliderNav = $('.slider-nav');
    const sliderContent = $('.slider-content');
    const sliderFor = $('.slider-for');
    let selector = '.slick-current > img, .slick-current > #video-slide > iframe';
    let index = $(selector).attr('index');
    if (index == 0) {
        const sliderForPromise = new Promise((resolve) => {
            sliderFor.slick('slickPrev');
            sliderFor.on('afterChange', function () {
                resolve();
            });
        });
    
        sliderForPromise.then(() => {
            sliderContent.slick('slickPrev');
        }).then(() => {
            sliderNav.slick('slickPrev');
        });
    } else {
        sliderFor.slick('slickPrev');
    }
}
```